# IE won't toggle element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this JavaScript on my page to toggle a div and switching between two images

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function toggleArchiv() {
  document.getElementById('cat').toggle();
  var image = document.getElementById('arrow');
  if (image.src == 'bullet_arrow_down.png')
   {
    image.src = 'bullet_arrow_up.png';
   }
   else
   {
    image.src = 'bullet_arrow_down.png';
   }
  }
</script>
```

Works fine on modern browsers, but IE keeps saying there is an error at that line

```
document.getElementById('cat').toggle();
```

So it doesn't toggle the div and neither switches the image. What to do?

Comment: `document.getElementById('cat')` (an Element) has no method, `toggle`. Are you adding this method to the prototype yourself?

Comment: Not that I know. But why does it work in FF? It could be that one of the used JS-Libraries adds that method, but why doesn't IE understand that then... I'll check

Comment: Older versions of IE don't give you access to DOM prototypes.  You can access them if your page is rendered in IE8 in standards mode. Which libraries are you using?

Comment: Also comparing `image.src` won't work, in any browser. When you read that property you will get an absolute URL back eg. `http://www.example.com/img/bullet_arrow_down.png` which will not match the relative URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're using the PrototypeJS library.  The library will add methods to DOM elements, in this particular case it's adding `HTMLElement.prototype.toggle`.  DOM prototyping is only supported in IE8 and later and it must be rendering in standards mode.  In order to get it working in all browsers, use the `$()` method instead of `getElementById()`:

```
$('cat').toggle();
```

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/toggle/

Comment: Funny enough that I actually was using IE8 and it didn't work there - thus I haven't even bothered trying IE7.

Comment: @Apo: it's likely that your document wasn't rendering in IE8 standards mode then.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is calling toggle() on a HTMLElement not a jQuery object. You should use the jQuery selector instead of getElementById() like this:

```
$('#cat').toggle();
```